# How to parse google for a specific site and date range?

Tags: java, parsing, java-7, google-search

I am trying to get details of a website on how frequent the site is updated and for that I search for the google using its standard search keywords and get the desired result.

See url https://www.google.co.in/search?q=site:www.codingeek.com&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:10/11/2016,cd_max:19/11/2016

In the above query I have searched for codingeek website for a date range 10-Nov-2016 to 19-Nov-2016.

But when I try to hit the same URL from my Java program it ignores the date conditions and sends the normal results. Example - https://www.google.co.in/search?q=site:www.codingeek.com

I use `HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().setUserAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)").build();` to connect to the page and have used JSoup to parse and process the returned HTML data.

Is there any way to solve this issue or will google never returns the same values in browser and in program?

Answer (score 0):

Try URLEncoder

```
String url = "https://www.google.co.in/search?q="
            + URLEncoder.encode("site:www.codingeek.com", "UTF-8")
            + "&tbs=" + URLEncoder.encode("cdr:1,cd_min:10/11/2016,cd_max:19/11/2016", "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Still it is giving the same results and ignoring the dates(I have copied the code you have written).

Comment: try  with google custom search api.  https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/customsearch/v1

Comment: For this i need to have some keys and stuff and it is limited to some sites only as per my limited research.
However, in the mean time I have tried and successfully done this task by using htmlunit and it is giving proper results.